# How do I write a program that sorts this list in excel?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have used the search function before asking this question, and no one has asked this before.

This program is able to sort through a list in excel and then **output the cheapest prices for a given specification.**

Note: I don't know how to format a spreadsheet in stackoverflow, so I'll just link an excel file, hopefully this is not against the rules.

For example, given this list (real data but with phone numbers and names removed): [example list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13M9jx3EcmDc2hAVFfY2-d8ik9Hd9zs4DxGn9Du_dUCs/edit?usp=sharing)

So if I were to sort through this list myself, it would take a long time.

This is how I would do it manually. Firstly, find all the specs and put the cheapest prices like this: (Note, pf is partially furnished and ff is fully furnished. 3r2b means 3 bedrooms 2 bathrooms)

3r2b ff RM 3500

3r2b pf RM 3200

2+1r 2b pf RM 3000

2+1r 2b ff RM 3500

2+1r 3b ff RM 3000

3+1r3b ff RM 5500

4r3b ff 
RM 4500

Then based on this now sorted data, output the cheapest prices like this:

3r2b ff RM 3500

3r2b pf RM 3200

2+1r 3b ff RM 3000

4r3b ff RM 4500

So the program is able to go through a list and then sort it. After sorting all the data, the output should be like the one I did above.

I need some general ideas on how I might write a program like this. Some pointers, technical stuff, anything will help.

Hopefully I have been as clear as possible with what I'm trying to achieve, if not, I will clarify further at the comments below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step should be to restucture your file to contain sortable data. So far your sample file contains inconsistent formatting. One way to move forward might be to transform the data into a regular table first. This transformation might be aided by the following little split function

```
Function mysplit(r As Range)
  mysplit = split(r, Chr(10))
End Function
```

This function can be referenced in your table by entering it as a *matrix function* for 4 columns (select four consecutive cells [c1:f1], enter the formula `=mysplit(a[1])` and submit with `<cntrl><shift><enter>`).

1. insert a new module into your Excel workbook
   [image: insert a new module into your Excel workbook]
2. reference the newly defined function as a matrix function for a cell range
   [image: reference the newly defined function as a matrix function for a cell range]

(Note the curly brackets `{= ... }` around the formula!)

Then copy this formula down until all data has been captured.

However, the result will still need to be tidied further manually, as you can see below (I placed the result in a new table, starting at column A):

```
A      B        C   D
--------------------------------
1283   3r2b     Ff  3700
1092   2+1r 2b  pf  3000 - 3200
1283   3r2b     Pf  3500
1283   3r2b     pf  3500
1092   2+1r 2b  pf  3000 - 3200

... following entries still need futher processing ...

Facing Damansara Perdana    2 Rooms + 1 Hobby Room  2 toilets   1099 SQf 
SIE 1705SF  4R3B    FF  PRICE 6000
This is my unit 35-2 1700sqft   4r3b    Ff  Price asking 5500 
1092sf  2+1r 2b     ff  
1092sf  2+1r3b  Ff  Price 3000 
Reflection 1099sf   3r+b    Ff  Asking 3.7k Min can go 3.5k only
rental min 5.5k thks.   .1700sq ft  3+1r3b  fully furnished unit
1092sf  2+1r 2b     ff  price 3600
size 1283sf     3r2b    pf  price 3500
1705sf  Pf  Second preference is to rent at RM 4,500 partly furnished with 1 year term  
1298sf  3r2b    pf  3300
size 1092sf     2+1r 2b     pf  price 3000 - 3200 
size 1092sf     2+1r2b  pf  price 3000 - 3300 
size 1283sf     3r2b    pf  price 3200
```

But even in my first "processed" lines there are deficiencies: the columns B and D still contain badly formatted data. There is composite data in B (r and b counts) and column D sometimes contains ranges.

Once you have a fully regular table, sorting it will be trivial:

```
A      B C D   E     F    G
sf     r x b   state ask  min
--------------------------------
1283   3   2   Ff    3700
1092   2 1 2   pf    3200 3000
1283   3   2   Pf    3500
1283   3   2   pf    3500
1092   2 1 2   pf    3200 3000
...
```

But without a regular **consistent** formatting, *meaningful* sorting is nigh to impossible.

Comment: This is very useful Sir, so first I need to make everything consistent and regular. But sir, can you explain the mysplit function a little more? I don't quite understand that bit.

Comment: @johndoe666, please have a  look at the images I just added to the post. They illustrate how to create and use the function `mysplit()`. But, as I explained already: the biggest part of the restructuring work still requires manual interaction ...

Comment: Manual restructuring is fine with me, thank you for your time and help Sir !